What is happening with my mouse?
Every time I right-click or left-click in a game, my camera moves 45 degrees to the right, and this only happens with Raw Input on. Also, clicking left-click on a mouse test website shows that it also triggers a middle click.
But when I check my mouse button in a program called X-Mouse Button, the left click doesn't trigger the middle click, which is very weird.
But the most annoying thing about this is it makes it impossible to close tabs or switch tabs, clicking the address bar doesn't work, and clicking my taskbar and desktop icons and windows sometimes freezes them, which I had to Ctrl+Alt+Delete to make them work again.
And yes, I have tried switching mice, which doesn't help because the problem is still there. I have also tried uninstalling drivers and reinstalling them again, but it doesn't work.
The only temporary fix I found is to disable the middle click in the X-Mouse Button, which makes the left click work again. But the 45 degrees camera rotates whenever I left or right-click in the game, is still there.
The last time my mouse functioned normally was before I installed VirtualBox and VMware Workstation 10. The mouse problem also affects my laptop touchpad, which is annoying.

Do you get the same rotation when using a different mouse? Is the different mouse the same type of mouse (brand/model) or different? Is it a new mouse or old/used? If you connect the first mouse to a different computer does it have the same issues? I'm guessing the problem is with the computer, so you should begin by uninstalling any and all software regarding the mouse, including X-Mouse Button. You should also go to Device Manager and delete the mouse entries found there. You may need to familiarize yourself with navigating Windows via keyboard for this. Then restart.

However, note that you should NOT be using Windows 7 connected to the internet in any way, shape, or form at this time. Unless you have a second computer to find and download any necessary software for this mouse, you should only rely on any default drivers Windows has with it.

@music2myear The different mouse that I tested on my laptop is completely different from my mouse, and it doesn't have the same issues on other computers. I already knew the problem is from my laptop, but have no idea on how to fix it. Any idea?

I already gave some steps for you to try.

@music2myear Tried uninstalling the mouse driver and restart but it didn't work. To be honest I don't think the program that I installed is causing the problem. The last time the mouse is still function normally is before I install VMware Workstation and VirtualBox to my computer, which I uninstalled when the mouse problem starts to occur. But the mouse problem is still there. I'm suspecting that my computer has a virus, but the antivirus program didn't find any (yes I have let it scan my entire computer). Any idea on how to fix this?

Which game and what mouse do you have?

@DrZoo My mouse is just a normal office mouse with some dpi options (EBLUE EMS816), the weird rotation when I click happens to all games that have Raw Input on, but doesn't happen with games that don't have Raw Input.

A virus is very unlikely to cause the symptoms you describe. It's common for many people to assume something behaving unexpectedly is a virus, but is is also common for them to be wrong. Viruses don't want to reveal themselves, and they are usually focused on something other than making a mouse misbehave.

Are you using xmouse by chance? You could also open up task manager and copy paste all of the running processes into your answer. It might help spot something that could be a culprit.

@DrZoo I'm only using X-Mouse Button to disable Middle Click because it helps me temporary fix the taskbar issue, but not the weird rotation in games.

So you didn't have xmouse installed at all beforehand? I found a forum post where someone had the same issue you did, and xmouse was the culprit. As soon as they uninstalled xmouse the problem was gone.

@DrZoo Oh, I have found the answer to all of this chaos.  Thank you for your help, really appriciate it!

@music2myear Also you too. Thanks for helping me!

The real answer I found out is that it is not my laptop failing or a virus or something, but the hardware of my mouse is causing the problem.
I borrowed my friend's mouse, and it was okay. The reason why I said another mouse didn't work earlier is that because the middle click keeps pressing down, switching to another mouse without pressing the middle click again will hold it down, making the issue remain there.
